# Countdown for the message "you can ask once in 40 minutes"

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, rate-limiting

Instead of the static message, "you can ask only once in 40 minutes", maybe display a countdown?

40 minutes are quite long; what I do I left the tab open and retry submitting after a time I feel the 40 minutes might be over, or have to notice the time they end upfront.

Comment: 40 minutes is too long, I don't think user/OP will keep  refreshing the page

Comment: Another option would be to change the message to something like: _You can ask a question again after 17:11_

Comment: This question is currently tagged as [tag:support], but I assume this is actually a [tag:feature-request]? Anyway, take a walk, browse the internet, watch viral YouTube videos, or read random SE questions and their related questions, and 40 minutes will go by... or just reach 125 rep on that site.

Comment: I agree with this post. I have no idea why SE/SO has not implemented this or do not show signs of even thinking about adding this feature.